# Select SUM() as a variable in a for Loop

Tags: php, mysql, variables, for-loop, sum

I'm trying to generate XML from database and need to gather a specific amount of data based on the average from a column. This can vary from anywhere between 5 to 30 queries for the `$numItems` variable.

I need to execute a for loop and assign the column name in the `SUM($variable)` but I'm not getting any data (but no errors either).

Here is my code:

```
for ($t = 1; $t <= $numItems; $t++){

$query = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(column'".$t."') AS value_sum FROM scoring WHERE ID='" . $userID . "' AND name ='" . $name . "'")); 

$q = $query['value_sum'] / $totalUsers;

echo "<output".$t.">" . $q . "</output".$t.">\n";

}
```

The problem is assigning the `SUM(column1)` variable name for the column I'm getting data from, when I write the queries individually it works, but assigning the variable within the statement is causing a problem. Can any one give me any pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this situation, echo that SQL and try to execute it on the MySQL terminal directly. You will soon be able to get an idea, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like bad escaping/concatenation around the column name...

```
"SELECT SUM(column{$t}) AS value_sum FROM scoring WHERE ID='{$userID}' AND name ='{$name}'"
```

Is that what you want?

Also use [**PDO**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)!

Comment: Thanks Ficuscr, works perfectly. I'll read up on PDO, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you might have extra single quotes in your query.  I think it should be:

```
"SELECT SUM(column".$t.")..."
```

You should also consider doing a single select.  Doing multiple database calls inside a for loop will be a huge performance problem.  You could write a single select like this:

```
"SELECT SUM(column1), SUM(column2), SUM(column3),..."
```

Comment: Or a `GROUP BY`.  Salient comment, fewer SQL calls the better.